# How to influence the size of the off heap memory?

Tags: performance, neo4j, heap-memory

I use the 2.1.6 version on Neo4j and I try to change the size of the off heap memory.
I have 2GO of RAM. I put 1GO for the heap size with the parameter`wrapper.java.initmemory` and the `wrapper.java.maxmemory`.
To change the size of the off heap memory, I add the parameters:

```
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory  
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory
```

But when I launch my program, and do a JConsole, the size of the off heap is always 44Mo at the start and increases until a maximum: 73Mo although I change the value of the neostore parameters.
Is there another parameter to add to change this size?

Answer (score 0):

You configure the max sizes, they will only be used if needed.